# Gifting in iTunes to people in other countries

Tags: itunes, gift

Christmas is coming up, and I'm currently living in a country (UK) that's a completely different iTunes store from my family (US).  So I'm wondering if I can gift things in the iTunes store if I'm in a different country than the recipient.  If I gift something from the UK store, can someone in the US download the items?  I'm not even sure if there's a way for me to go to the US version, let alone try to gift an item from there.

Comment: You can change the store in iTunes by clicking on the country flag icon at the bottom of the screen. So if you do have a US iTunes account, you can gift them that way (if that is a verb).

Comment: That is a verb, and the answer, I will post a work around as well. +1

Comment: Apps that you purchase in the UK store are only downloadable to other UK users. I tried switching the country of my iTunes store to the target country, but it won't work unless I have a credit card with a billing address in that country. And you can't gift apps (not sure about music or other content) from a gift card balance. Help, you guys!

Comment: Are you asking about apps or music or both?

Comment: I left this open to pretty much anything that I could gift through the iTunes store. App, music, movies, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [Apple support](http://store.apple.com/us/help/gifting), from the U.S., you can gift physical goods to:

> Mexico, 15 countries in Europe, and four countries in Southeast Asia (Indonesia, Malaysia, the Philippines, and Thailand).

Those 15 European countries are: Austria, Belgium, Denmark, Finland, France, Germany, Ireland, Italy, Netherlands, Norway, Portugal, Spain, Sweden, Switzerland, United Kingdom. Anywhere else and it seems you need a credit card with a billing address in the target country to send gifts.

However, this does NOT apply to gifting apps:

> [iTunes] Gift Cards and Certificates are valid for use only in the country in which they were purchased. Only residents of the U.S may redeem gift certificates purchased in the U.S.

Answer (score 6):

You can't.

From the Apple's [iTunes: Sending iTunes Gifts](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2736?viewlocale=en_US) page:

> You can't redeem purchased gifts outside of the country of purchase. For example, an iTunes Gift purchased in France can't be redeemed in an iTunes Store outside of France.

Apple haven't yet worked out that people move around the world, and have friends and family in different countries. To give the benefit of the doubt to Apple, perhaps it's to do with tax and legal frameworks, but then how come I can transfer thousands of pounds from a bank account in one country to a bank account in another, yet can't transfer a few quid between two iTunes accounts in different countries?

But then "iTunes" and "easy and convenient" are at opposite ends of the spectrum.

Answer (score 1):

a work around is to visit an online store such as [amazon.com](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002H9PTEE) and buy them on that site for delivery to the USA address. This way you are buying the product in the USA for someone in the USA.

There is no confusion over who it is for or where it can be redeemed.

Comment: A down vote without a plausible explanation? Thanks.

Comment: Well, even if your answer does give a workaround, it's not really answering the question (which is about the iTunes store, not Amazon). Downvote's not mine though :)

Comment: hence why I started with 'a work around' which I said I would post after confirming the answer was the comment made on the question. seems strange to down vote without edit or comment.

Comment: I'm guessing the down voters didn't understand you were talking about buying an American iTunes gift card via Amazon and using that to buy the apps for friends in America. The original question is about gifting things in the iTunes store, presumably apps one-by-one, rather than buying a card and giving that to someone.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I just went trough the same issue when preparing for the 2014 holiday season.

Except for few exceptions, you cannot send iTunes gift to accounts in other countries. More specifically, you can send the gift but the people will not be able to redeem them. They end up stuck with a useless email.

What you can do is send iTunes gift cards. These can be sent electronically and can be purchased for one country's specific store, in your case USA, from another country. You can purchase the codes from Apple, but in my case it was more convenient to buy them from eBay, since it allowed me to pay with a non-US credit card.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - just go to Country specific iTunes site and purchase the gift card as Guest (don't  checkout via your iTunes account.)

For example, I live in the US and I want to purchase an Ireland iTunes gift card in euros for my cousin who lives in Dublin. I would go to www.apple.com, go to the bottom right corner of the website, and select "Ireland" as my country. Then proceed to purchase the gift card and follow instructions to check out. If you use an email address the same as your iTunes account, it'll ask you if you want to sign in. Don't log in. Just select the option to check out as Guest. This will allow you to purchase an iTunes gift card for a different country.

Comment: What you're talking about is an Apple store e-gift card that can be used to buy physical goods in an Apple retail store or an Apple online store. In the small print it says you can't use it in the iTunes store.

Answer (score -2):

Amazon seems the best way to go. You can't workaround it and make a fake account in the USA unless you use a credit card from the USA. I was wondering this also since I'm in Canada trying to send a gift to the USA  or China but I guess I'll just try to find another online gift to send.